# Gzcompress записывает в БД кракозябры

Tags: php, массивы, serialize

Есть поле в БД с типом text и сравнением utf8_general_ci.
В данном поле планирую хранить массив, делаю следующим образом:

```
$ser_arr = serialize($products_arr); //выполняю serialize
$small = gzcompress($ser_arr); //сжимаю строку
echo $small;
```

Выводит на экран какую-то дичь (2 строка):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом на первой строке до сжатия все нормально.

Соответственно, такие символы в БД никак не записать. Вопрос, это нормальное поведение или что-то не так с кодировкой где-то? (В файле стоит utf-8)

ДОПОЛНЕНО:
Попытка записать информацию в ячейку с типом BLOB оказалась удачной, однако при вытаскивании данных из ячейки происходит ошибка gzuncompress(): data error.
Причем ошибка возникает только в модели (пишу на yii2), во вьюшке все прекрасно достается.

Может есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: А зачем вы сжимаете строку? Сохраняйте в базу `$ser_arr`.

Comment: @Visman ну типа чтоб места меньше занимало, это очевидно же)

Comment: Да, предполагается, что там в последствии будет больше элементов, поэтому лучше сжимать) @Visman

Comment: @DumbSailor а почему в базу нельзя?  при нужной кодировке разве не  запишется? а при извлечении делать `gzuncompress()`..... но вообще это какая-то странная оптимизация. они же не будут у вас заниматься по гигабайту в ячейку, не правда ли?

Comment: В Базу при кодировке utf8 записывается только первый символ - как видно на картинке это "x", ибо он нормальный. Какую кодировку поставить, чтобы это записалось- не знаю, честно говоря, сижу перебираю.

Comment: Ну смотря какой тип колонки еще.... gzcompress - это BLOB...... А в поле с типом text, понятное дело что не полезет.........

Comment: Вы открыли мне глаза на этот мир. Благодарю!)

Comment: Но что-то только оно обратно вытаскиваться не хочет в модели, выдает gzuncompress(): data error. Во вьюшке без проблем. Странно

Comment: а что вы собственно ожидали там увидеть? что текст после компрессии остался таким же читаемым, как и до?

Comment: Ну, скажем, последовательность символов, которая бы могла храниться в типе text, но до этого я не знала о принципах работы gzcompress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело оказалось в используемом фреймворке (Yii2). Точнее в обращении к БД через ActiveRecords методом find(). 
Честно говоря, научиться обращаться с результатами такого запроса у меня так и не получилось, но переделав запрос под обычный select все без проблем записалось и вытащилось из БД.

Comment: Дело не в фреймворке, а в том, как вам и написали в комментариях к ответу, что вы пытаетесь хранить бинарные данные (результат gzcompress) в поле текстового типа. Потом, почему gzcompress, а не deflate? Скрытый плюс в том, что gzip-последовательности можно конкатенировать методом "в лоб", но вряд ли вы об этом думали. Потом, если сжимается поток достаточно длинных данных, то это одно дело, а на коротких данных степень сжатия будет ниже. Возможно, сжатие в вашем случае вообще не имеет смысла.

Comment: Проблема запросов фреймворка возникла уже после того, как тип данных был исправлен на Blob, замечание про тип к сведению я приняла сразу же и исправила)
Почему gzcompress? Ответ тривиально прост: потому что я не профессионал и делаю пока, как знаю, а знала я только этот метод) Теперь обязательно почитаю о deflate и разнице между ними. 
Считаю, что сжатие лучше сделать, потому что объем данных может быть гораздо больше, чем в приведенном мной примере.

Comment: Есть несколько форматов сжатых данных в zlib: 1) Собственно, последовательность блоков, сжатых deflate. Это битовые блоки. 2) Данные в формате ZLIB. К deflate добавляется некоторый заголовок и контрольная сумма Adler-32. Когда сервер выдает `Content-Type: deflate`, то на самом деле используется не чистый deflate, а именно такой формат. 3) Данные в формате GZIP. Имеют более длинный (не фиксировано) заголовок. Вероятно, вам нужен чистый deflate, поскольку для коротких данных сжатие будет небольшое, и вместе с заголовком (формат ZLIB или GZIP) размер может вообще превысить исходный.

Comment: Спасибо, так понятнее)